# Bulls eye plot of image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot the Bull's Eye diagram of an image. I tried these codes 
[Shade 'cells' in polar plot with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837296/shade-cells-in-polar-plot-with-matplotlib/15245850)

For Bull's Eye diagram I want to use different colors. Is there is any way to set this colors? In `color = choice(['navy','maroon','lightgreen'])` colors are repeating according as for loop iterates.

Does anyone know if in matplotlib there is a function correponding to matlab `bullseye()`?

Comment: can you explain better what you want to achieve and maybe how you would implement it?

Comment: I have array of theta, radii and width value.
According to this theta and radii I have to color the sectors.

Comment: would you mind editing your question adding these details and possible providing some mock data and possible an essential implementation so that people can cut, paste and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a specific `bullseye` method in `matplotlib`, but comparing what the matlab function does and the right plot in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10838501/1860757), I think that you should be able to get what you want playing a bit with the radius coordinates. E.g. (borrowing from the aforesaid answer)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta, r = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0.2:1:10j]
z = np.random.random(theta.size).reshape(theta.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

ax.pcolormesh(theta, r, z)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])

plt.show()
```

plots [image: this]

I don't understand exactly what you mean with the question about the colors. `ax.pcolormesh` accept either a [colormap](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/show_colormaps.html) or a matplotlib [color](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html). If you want specific colors you can play with those two parameters and/or create your own colormap.

Answer (score 2):

To provide something similar to the matlab function you mentioned, I drafted some code (shared on git hub as well) for the creation of bullseyes with any number of sector for each radial subdivision. The colour is given by the colormap and by the values below the sector. Moreover, this allows for the modification the centering of the radial subdivision.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


def bulls_eye(ax, data, cmap=None, norm=None, raidal_subdivisions=(2, 8, 8, 11),
              centered=(True, False, False, True), add_nomenclatures=True, cell_resolution=128,
              pfi_where_to_save=None, colors_bound='-k'):
    """
    Clockwise, from smaller radius to bigger radius.
    :param ax:
    :param data:
    :param cmap:
    :param norm:
    :param raidal_subdivisions:
    :param centered:
    :param add_nomenclatures:
    :param cell_resolution:
    :param pfi_where_to_save:
    :return:
    """
    line_width = 1.5
    data = np.array(data).ravel()

    if cmap is None:
        cmap = plt.cm.viridis

    if norm is None:
        norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max())

    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 768)
    r = np.linspace(0, 1, len(raidal_subdivisions)+1)

    nomenclatures = []
    if isinstance(add_nomenclatures, bool):
        if add_nomenclatures:
            nomenclatures = range(1, sum(raidal_subdivisions)+1)
    elif isinstance(add_nomenclatures, list) or isinstance(add_nomenclatures, tuple):
        assert len(add_nomenclatures) == sum(raidal_subdivisions)
        nomenclatures = add_nomenclatures[:]
        add_nomenclatures = True


    # Create the circular bounds
    line_width_circular = line_width
    for i in range(r.shape[0]):
        if i == range(r.shape[0])[-1]:
            line_width_circular = int(line_width / 2.)
        ax.plot(theta, np.repeat(r[i], theta.shape), colors_bound, lw=line_width_circular)

    # iterate over cells divided by radial subdivision
    for rs_id, rs in enumerate(raidal_subdivisions):
        for i in range(rs):
            cell_id = sum(raidal_subdivisions[:rs_id]) + i
            theta_i = - i * 2 * np.pi / rs + np.pi / 2
            if not centered[rs_id]:
                theta_i += (2 * np.pi / rs) / 2
            theta_i_plus_one = theta_i - 2 * np.pi / rs  # clockwise
            # Create colour fillings for each cell:
            theta_interval = np.linspace(theta_i, theta_i_plus_one, cell_resolution)
            r_interval = np.array([r[rs_id], r[rs_id+1]])
            angle  = np.repeat(theta_interval[:, np.newaxis], 2, axis=1)
            radius = np.repeat(r_interval[:, np.newaxis], cell_resolution, axis=1).T
            z = np.ones((cell_resolution, 2)) * data[cell_id]
            ax.pcolormesh(angle, radius, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

            # Create radial bounds
            if rs  > 1:
                ax.plot([theta_i, theta_i], [r[rs_id], r[rs_id+1]], colors_bound, lw=line_width)
            # Add centered nomenclatures if needed
            if add_nomenclatures:
                if rs == 1 and rs_id ==0:
                    cell_center = (0, 0)
                else:
                    cell_center = ((theta_i + theta_i_plus_one) / 2., r[rs_id] + .5 * r[1] )

                if isinstance(nomenclatures[0], (int, long, float, complex)):
                    ax.annotate(r"${:.3g}$".format(nomenclatures[cell_id]), xy=cell_center,
                                xytext=(cell_center[0], cell_center[1]),
                                horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', size=8)
                else:
                    ax.annotate(nomenclatures[cell_id], xy=cell_center,
                                xytext=(cell_center[0], cell_center[1]),
                                horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', size=12)

    ax.grid(False)
    ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.set_xticklabels([])

    if pfi_where_to_save is not None:
        plt.savefig(pfi_where_to_save, format='pdf', dpi=200)


def multi_bull_eyes(multi_data, cbar=None, cmaps=None, normalisations=None,
                    global_title=None, canvas_title='title', titles=None, units=None, raidal_subdivisions=(2, 8, 8, 11),
                    centered=(True, False, False, True), add_nomenclatures=(True, True, True, True),
                    pfi_where_to_save=None, show=True):
    plt.clf()
    n_fig = len(multi_data)
    if cbar is None:
        cbar = [True] * n_fig
    if cmaps is None:
        cmaps = [mpl.cm.viridis] * n_fig
    if normalisations is None:
        normalisations = [mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=np.min(multi_data[i]), vmax=np.max(multi_data[i]))
                          for i in range(n_fig)]
    if titles is None:
        titles = ['Title {}'.format(i) for i in range(n_fig)]

    h_space = 0.15 / n_fig
    h_dim_fig = .8
    w_dim_fig = .8 / n_fig

    def fmt(x, pos):
        # a, b = '{:.2e}'.format(x).split('e')
        # b = int(b)
        # return r'${} \times 10^{{{}}}$'.format(a, b)
        return r"${:.4g}$".format(x)

    # Make a figure and axes with dimensions as desired.
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3 * n_fig, 4))
    fig.canvas.set_window_title(canvas_title)
    if global_title is not None:
        plt.suptitle(global_title)

    for n in range(n_fig):
        origin_fig = (h_space * (n + 1) + w_dim_fig * n, 0.15)
        ax = fig.add_axes([origin_fig[0], origin_fig[1], w_dim_fig, h_dim_fig], polar=True)
        bulls_eye(ax, multi_data[n], cmap=cmaps[n], norm=normalisations[n], raidal_subdivisions=raidal_subdivisions,
                  centered=centered, add_nomenclatures=add_nomenclatures[n])
        ax.set_title(titles[n], size=10)

        if cbar[n]:
            origin_cbar = (h_space * (n + 1) + w_dim_fig * n, .15)
            axl = fig.add_axes([origin_cbar[0], origin_cbar[1], w_dim_fig, .05])
            cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(axl, cmap=cmaps[n], norm=normalisations[n], orientation='horizontal',
                                            format=ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))
            cb1.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
            if units is not None:
                cb1.set_label(units[n])

    if pfi_where_to_save is not None:
        plt.savefig(pfi_where_to_save, format='pdf', dpi=330)
    if show:
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Very dummy data:
    data = np.array(range(29)) + 1

    # TEST bull-eye three-fold
    if True:

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8), nrows=1, ncols=3,
                               subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
        fig.canvas.set_window_title('Left Ventricle Bulls Eyes')

        # First one:
        cmap = mpl.cm.viridis
        norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=29)

        bulls_eye(ax[0], data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        ax[0].set_title('Bulls Eye ')

        axl = fig.add_axes([0.14, 0.15, 0.2, 0.05])
        cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(axl, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal')
        cb1.set_label('Some Units')

        # Second one
        cmap2 = mpl.cm.cool
        norm2 = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=29)

        bulls_eye(ax[1], data, cmap=cmap2, norm=norm2)
        ax[1].set_title('Bulls Eye ')

        axl2 = fig.add_axes([0.41, 0.15, 0.2, 0.05])
        cb2 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(axl2, cmap=cmap2, norm=norm2, orientation='horizontal')
        cb2.set_label('Some other units')

        # Third one
        cmap3 = mpl.cm.winter
        norm3 = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=29)

        bulls_eye(ax[2], data, cmap=cmap3, norm=norm3)
        ax[2].set_title('Bulls Eye third')

        axl3 = fig.add_axes([0.69, 0.15, 0.2, 0.05])
        cb3 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(axl3, cmap=cmap3, norm=norm3, orientation='horizontal')
        cb3.set_label('Some more units')

        plt.show()

    if True:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 7))
        fig.canvas.set_window_title('Bulls Eyes - segmentation assessment')

        # First and only:
        cmap = mpl.cm.viridis
        norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=29)

        ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7], polar=True)
        bulls_eye(ax, data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        ax.set_title('Bulls Eye')

        axl = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.15, 0.8, 0.05])
        cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(axl, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal')
        cb1.set_label('Some Units')

        plt.show()

    if True:

        multi_data = [range(1,17), list( 0.000000001 * np.array(range(1,17))), list( 0.001 * np.array(range(1,17)))]
        print multi_data
        multi_bull_eyes(multi_data, raidal_subdivisions=(3,3,4,6),
                  centered=(True, True, True, True), add_nomenclatures=[True]*3)

        plt.show(block=True)
```

It is proposed within my code [LabelsManager](https://github.com/SebastianoF/LabelsManager) on github, that you are welcome to use.

Here is an example, for raidal_subdivisions=(2, 8, 8, 11), and centered=(True, False, False, True):
[image]